# Managing Recurring Bookings (allowing how many & cancellation of monthly membership)

Tags: user-expectation, user-centered-design

I am new here. I thought I give it a shot.

I am a product manager in a Startup offering a service that can be booked by clients on a monthly membership basis. I want to offer recurring bookings but in my head I can't find a user friendly, elegant way how to handle recurring bookings with a monthly cancellation option. Any thoughts on that?
Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello Katharina, welcome to UX.SE. Could you please clarify what you mean by "recurring bookings with a monthly cancellation option"? You need the user able to cancel just a single month, while the others will continue as scheduled (skipping that month's booking), or is the user only allowed to cancel the entire recurring series?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came into my mind was to refer to how MS Outlook handles reoccurring meetings.

The user will be given the option to edit just the one appointment or the entire series.

[image]

Here are some references for your consideration:

https://www.customguide.com/outlook/recurring-appointments